# Open source/Free real time remote desktop software for linux/Mac Operating systems?

Tags: open-source, remote-access, desktop-client, remote-desktop

Use case:
Accessing my office desktop, from home, as if I am sitting in front of the office desk :)

Tools Used:

- [Chrome remote desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp/reviews?hl=en) (latency, seems to be very slow)
- Team Viewer (not free)

Any other tools apart from the ones above mentioned ?

Comment: Remote Desktop built into Windows?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name forgot to mention it is for linux/mac systems.

Comment: [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vnc)? There are multiple applications (client as well as server side), so maybe you can give a few more hints on your requirements to narrow it down – e.g. price limit, or if you want it rather "small and lightweight" or with (which?) additional features etc.

Comment: Did not tried vnc , price == free 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## VNC

[image]

[**Virtual Network Computing (VNC)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) is an open protocol for remote screen sharing. It transmits the keyboard and mouse events from one computer to another, relaying the graphical screen updates back in the other direction, over a network. The protocol is intended to be cross-platform, enabling a BSD or Linux computer to display a remote Mac for example.

## Implementations

Some implementations are open-source and free-of-cost, while other implementations are commercially supported products. The remote computer must be running an VNC server app while the local computer runs a VNC client app.

## Apple

[Apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.) has bundled client and server implementations such as [Screen Sharing.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_Sharing) in various versions of [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS).

## RealVNC

[**RealVNC**](https://www.realvnc.com) is one prominent vendor of VNC products. I have successfully used older versions of their products. There are many other vendors to choose from as well.

## How it works

VNC is pixel-based. Basically, VNC works by taking the screen's display at any moment, dividing it up into a grid of squares, and then shipping an image of each square to the client.

This approach generally works well enough for monitoring a computer. But it has limitations. Slower network connections may cause the user to notice the squares occasionally being updated so the screen is not quite complete. Some apps that use unconventional drawing within their windows rather than the drawing methods provided by the host OS may not function properly, you may see little or no content of such apps’ windows. And video playing may, of course, be quite choppy.

Keep in mind that no screen-sharing solution will give you an absolutely smooth intact “as if I were there” experience.